# Python module not found

Tags: python

How do I import pyBarcode from the Python interpreter? According to the [pyBarcode documentation](http://packages.python.org/pyBarcode/barcode.html) the first step is to `import barcode`. When I try that it says there is no such module.

```
~# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2

>>> import barcode
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named barcode
```

Comment: Can you successfully `import barcode` from a script?

Comment: You need to install the module first, it's not included with Python.

Comment: Oops I hadn't installed it. Now I have. Resolved.

Comment: +1 for including full traceback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before using (`import`ing) pyBarcode, you must [install](https://bitbucket.org/whitie/python-barcode#rst-header-installation) it, for instance with

```
pip install pyBarcode
```

Comment: The link no longer works, you should provide the answer not only a link.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I updated the link and added the installation instructions.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the directory that contains the module is in your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Alternatively, you can use

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\path to pyBarcode")
import barcode
```