# "No Module name matrix_factorization_utilities" found

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I am a beginner in Machine Learning. 
I am getting this error in my machine learning recommendation model "**No Module name matrix_factorization_utilities" found**[Screen Shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1260J.png).
I am using Python 3 and Pycharm. Library numpy, pyMF pandas.

Comment: Have you installed scipy, cause the traceback shows that the file `matrix_factorizaton_utilities` tries to import scipy, but no module named scipy is found

Comment: I am unable to install scipy, it is showing some error to installed right type of pip and there are so many types of pip.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have scipy

Windows:

```
python -m pip install scipy
```

Linux:

```
pip install scipy
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you installed the module (as it is in your directory), so the next step is to make sure you the module is in your PYTHONPATH environment variable:
[Python module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587382/python-module-not-found)

Here is another website that may also help regarding the PYTHONPATH variable:
[How to fix "ImportError: No module named ..." error in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325923/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-error-in-python)

Also APorter1031 raises an excellent point - that may be the issue.